# Cytoscape: How do you import ABC file types with py2cytoscape's cyrest api?

Tags: python-3.x, cytoscape

I have a file of the type:

```
A B 0.123
A C 0.84
B D 0.52
...
```

Where the data are tab separated, and the first and second columns are the nodes, and the third is the associated edge weight.

When trying to import this file into cytoscape using py2cytoscape, I'm receiving an error:

```py
from py2cytoscape import cyrest
fileName="/Users/96v/Documents/lco/lcoAllAt25/lcoAll25/lcoAll25_top0.041pct_data/lcoAll25_top0.041pct.txt"
cyclient = cyrest.cyclient()
cyclient.network.import_file(dataTypeList='string,string,double', 
                             afile=fileName, 
                             delimiters='\t', 
                             indexColumnSourceInteraction="0", 
                             indexColumnTargetInteraction="1", 
                             verbose=True)
```

> 'http://localhost:1234/v1/commands/network/import file'
>
> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 cyclient.network.import_file(dataTypeList='string,string,double', afile=fileName, delimiters='\t', indexColumnSourceInteraction="0", indexColumnTargetInteraction="1", defaultInteraction="Edge Attribute",verbose=True)
> 2
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2cytoscape/cyrest/network.py in import_file(self, dataTypeList, defaultInteraction, delimiters, delimitersForDataList, afile, firstRowAsColumnNames, indexColumnSourceInteraction, indexColumnTargetInteraction, indexColumnTypeInteraction, NetworkViewRendererList, RootNetworkList, startLoadRow, TargetColumnList, verbose)
> 464         afile,firstRowAsColumnNames,indexColumnSourceInteraction,indexColumnTargetInteraction,
> 465         indexColumnTypeInteraction,NetworkViewRendererList,RootNetworkList,startLoadRow,TargetColumnList])
> --> 466         response=api(url=self.__url+"/import file", PARAMS=PARAMS, method="POST", verbose=verbose)
> 467         return response
> 468
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2cytoscape/cyrest/base.py in api(namespace, command, PARAMS, body, host, port, version, method, verbose, url, parse_params)
> 139             sys.stdout.flush()
> 140         r = requests.post(url = baseurl, json = PARAMS)
> --> 141         verbose_=checkresponse(r, verbose=verbose)
> 142         if (verbose) or (verbose_):
> 143             verbose=True
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2cytoscape/cyrest/base.py in checkresponse(r, verbose)
> 43     if 200 <= status < 300:
> 44         if verbose:
> ---> 45             print("response status "+status)
> 46             sys.stdout.flush()
> 47         res=None
>
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

The edge weights aren't being recognized, yet [the documentation](https://py2cytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cyrest/network/) isn't as verbose for this function.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After looking further at the GUI, I realized:

- Columns are not 0 indexed.
- Verbose has an error in it.

The below code works fine:

```py
from py2cytoscape import cyrest
fileName="pathToFile"
cyclient = cyrest.cyclient()
collection = cyclient.network.import_file(dataTypeList='string,string,double',
                                         afile=fileName, 
                                         delimiters='\t', 
                                         indexColumnSourceInteraction="1", 
                                         indexColumnTargetInteraction="2", 
                                         defaultInteraction="interacts with")
```

Comment: Great. You might also switch to py4cytoscape if you're planning to use this longer term. This is the officially-supported successor to py2cytoscape. Find details and doc links here: https://github.com/cytoscape/py4cytoscape.

Comment: The "fixed" code I see above still includes 0-indexing. Is that correct?
      indexColumnSourceInteraction="0"

Comment: Ah, thank you @AlexanderPico - I'll definitely checkout py4cytoscape, and also thanks for that catch! I edited the code to properly index!

Comment: I should also note - the error in the `verbose` parameter is fixed in the development branch on github, just not the published package.